# Python packages - same name, different install dir?

Tags: python, directory, installation, package

Here's my problem. I have two packages with the same name but with the different methods. Is it possible to change their default install directories without changing their names?

Comment: Are these custom packages that you created or third party?

Comment: Those are mine packages

Comment: Why do you need to keep them the same name?  Do they have the same purpose?

Comment: They will be installed on two different computers, but for testing purposes it would be convenient to install them in one environement

Comment: Then use a virtual environment.  That's what it's for.  Testing things like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python doesn't accept two packages with the same name so for complete answer 
see this links : https://stackoverflow.com/a/5063268/2867928

and https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path

Comment: I want to install them in one environment.