# How can python libraries of different projects be in the same package?

Tags: python, import, package

Let's say you have a big (python) software project called **Ninja**. There are several parts of the project like a *server* and a *client*, but also a common infrastructure library, which contains common classes and tools. Naturally I would create a package structure like this: `ninja.core`, `ninja.server` and `ninja.client`, where both the *server* and the *client* import `ninja.core` in some way. For development purposes (we use eclipse with Subversion) the *core*, *server* and *client* are maintained in different projects, thus resulting in a folder structure like this:

```
eclipse_workspace
|
>-Ninja_core
| |
| >-ninja
|   |
|   >-core
|
>-Ninja_client
| |
| >-ninja
|   |
|   >-client
.
.
.
```

Having a java background I assumed this would be possible, but it turned out (read: import errors) that this does not work. As pointed out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5063268/4890324), it is generally not possible to have both `ninja.core` and `ninja.client` ***unless*** they are subpackages of the same package `ninja`, which they are not. This gives rise to:

**Approach A:**

- Put the entire code in a single eclipse/svn project and have only one
  package `ninja` with the according subpackages.

In a production environment we want to be able to install *core* and *server* but not *client* or *core* and *client* but not *server*. I might be mistaken, but as far as I understand python packages, this would not be possible with approach A. Keeping the projects separate but compatible, it appears to be useful to use packages with the names `ninja_core`,`ninja_client` and `ninja_server`, which does in fact solve the import problems and has everything running smoothly in the development setup. To meet the requirement of being able to install *server* and *client* independently, I came up with the idea of:

**Approach B:**

- Create a new project called *ninja* which contains the package `ninja`
- let the `__init__.py` of `ninja` import the other libraries (if installed) in a way that they appear to be inside `ninja`.

I have not gotten this to work so far and I think it might not even be possible. I was thinking of something like this:

```py
# __init__.py of ninja
import ninja_core as core
# or this:
from ninja_core import core
# or this:
import ninja_core.core
```

I tried these and have gotten import errors again. After googling for ways to combine python packages and not finding anything related to my problem I came here.

I was thinking that maybe the whole thing is a design fault. Should *client* and *server* even be in the same package if they can be installed independently? Is it a bad idea to want to be able to install the client and server independently? Why can I *extend* packages in java, but not in python? What is the idea behind that?

**tl;dr**

I am developing the **Ninja** library where a user should be able to do `import ninja.client` and `import ninja.server`. It needs to be possible to install the libraries for *client* and *server* separately. How does one achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provided you leave the top-level namespace `ninja` empty, this is already natively supported in Python 3.3 and up, see [PEP 420](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/); all you have to do is create the `ninja` directory and *leave out the `__init__.py` file in that directory*:

```
eclipse_workspace
|
>-Ninja_core
| |
| >-ninja
|   |
|   >-core
|       |
|       >-__init__.py
|
>-Ninja_client
| |
| >-ninja
|   |
|   >-client
|       |
|       >-__init__.py
```

The `ninja` directories remain empty apart from the child `core` and `client` directories. Those directories *do* have `__init__.py` files.

In earlier Python versions, you can add support for namespaces by using [`setuptools` namespace packages](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#namespace-packages). The Zope and Plone projects have been releasing namespaced packages using `setuptools` for years now.

The basic principle is that you make sure your projects are packages with `setup.py` file, and are either installed in [development mode](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#development-mode) or as end-products. Your `ninja` directories *do* then have a `__init__.py` file, but these *must* contain the following line only:

```
__import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)
```

and the `setup.py` file for each project must declare the namespace:

```
setup(
    # ...
    namespace_packages = ['ninja']
)
```

Comment: It works, but since the `ninja` folder does not contain a `__init__.py` eclipse does not recognize any of the subfolders to be packages. Is there an option or an easy fix for this?

Comment: Sorry, no idea; I don't use Eclipse or PyDev myself; a quick google shows others have complained about that but I don't see any easy fixes for you.