# Using Python packages that share a base name

Tags: python, python-import, python-packaging

Consider two packages: `x.y.z` and `x.y.w`

Suppose I already have `x.y.z` installed via `pip` and I am testing `x.y.w` locally.

It seems that if I try to run `import x.y.z` it will fail with the error `No module named x.y.z` even though it's installed.  If I switch directory, I can import it just fine, but then I won't have `x.y.w`.  Is there any way to have both importable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to use two Python packages with the same name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062793/is-it-possible-to-use-two-python-packages-with-the-same-name)

Comment: Not quite, I don't really see a solution there.

Comment: @CoryNezin I think the answer is that it isn’t possible.

Comment: The solution I posted below works, I just don't understand why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following to some of my `__init__.py` files seems to have worked:

```
from pkgutil import extend_path
__path__ = extend_path(__path__, __name__)
```

(from https://docs.python.org/3/library/pkgutil.html)

However I'm not really sure why/how it worked.

Anyone care to explain?

Comment: You should read more about _namespace packages_. For example you could start with [PyPA's guide on "Packaging namespace packages"](https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/).