# Importing from two projects that export packages with the same name with Poetry

Tags: python, python-poetry

To detail the issue, let's say I have the following couple of pyproject.toml for my package that is to be used in another project (described later on below), one with different name than the root directory name:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "my-module-one"
version = "0.0.1"
description = ""
authors = []
packages = [
  { include = "some_module" }
]
```

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "my-module-two"
version = "0.0.1"
description = ""
authors = []
packages = [
  { include = "some_module" }
]
```

The project's directory structure is something like this (all managed using Poetry)

```
my-project/
|- my-module-one/
|  |- pyproject.toml
|  |- some_module/
|     |- something.py
|- my-module-two/
|  |- pyproject.toml
|  |- some_module/
|     |- something.py
|- app/
   |- main.py
   |- pyproject.toml
```

Now normally, we would install and import from either one using Poetry like so:

```
app$ poetry add ../my-module-one
```

And import it like so

```
# File: app/main.py
from some_module import something
```

This becomes a problem when importing both modules are installed because they export a directory with the same name in this case (and that I'm in no power to change this). So I would like to be able to import like so:

```
# Import some_module from my-module-one
from some_module_one import something as something_one

# Import some_module from my-module-two
from some_module_two import something as something_two
```

Is it possible to achieve this? If so, how can we do it?

P.S.: I kind of wanted to somehow alias the export from either one of the modules so `my-module-one`'s `something` becomes `something_one`, but can't figure out a way.

Comment: `from some_module_one import something as something_one` This is how we do aliasing in python exactly as you mentioned. Is it giving some error?

Comment: The issue is that I have two modules that exports the package called `some_module` in this example, and I need to install them both (my-module-one and my-module-two) in the `app` project. This is a problem because there's package name conflict. What that does is aliasing the import.

Comment: So both of the modules have the same name as well as the class/function you are interested in also has the same names?

Comment: Yes, the ones I'm concerned of even has the same function name in both modules. So, both `something.py` has a function with the name of some_function for example.

Comment: Short answer seems `NO`. More details here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062793/is-it-possible-to-use-two-python-packages-with-the-same-name#:~:text=Say%20you%20are%20given%20two,)%20mod3.py%20...

Comment: It might be possible if we can somehow alias the exports from the modules, but sadly I can't quite figure out a way to do this except changing the directory name and therefore directly changing the exported package name (which I don't think I'm in power to do this as this isn't my project).